# How to append a class by using jquery on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jquery click event is working on iphone. What i am trying to do is to append a class on clicking a particular div. The problem is click event is working(the alert message comming)  but the style is not affecting.Below is the code

```
$(document).on('click', '.boxes-3', function() {
  alert("hii12");
  $("#jithin").addClass('mHover'); 
});
```

Can anyone help on this....

Comment: Your code looks fine. Is mHover really the right class? Does #jithin get the class mHover? Probably you want to overwrite the #jithin styles through .mHover. The id styles will be used then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

Comment: the same code works fine in android device...but not in iphone

Comment: Probably a cache issue on your iOS browser.

Comment: Hi Terry, I cleared the cache....but still not working

Comment: Did you use a dev tool to verify the class actually gets added? Is the element fully visible on the iPhone browser? Is there no other html or css being used for the iPhone browser? Did you try something like `.mHover{color:red !important}` to rule out css specificity issues?

Comment: Hii Yezzz, other than safari browser...it is working fine. I do not understand y this not work in safari

Comment: I can get it to work by using hover event, but I don’t want that for the desktop version, since I want it to wait until until the user clicks.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with click event on that browser. Add touchstart or touchend event. You can just inline it `on('click touchstart',`

Comment: Thankyou for the reply Yezzz. You r ryt, there may be some problem with the click event in safari browser. I tried the touchstart event but it is some what similar like hover effect. I need the above mentioned class to append after clicking only...anyway thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: What do you mean touchstart is somewhat similar like hover? Be specific. Also, what other js code do you have on the page?

Comment: Hi Yezzz, sorry for the mistake. i need to display the above mentioned class on click event. I tried with the touch start, touchend events, it is all working. If i use the touchstart event then the class will append before the click itself and i went through some other sites and they are mentioning like safari browser is having issues with click, focus like events and it works fine with hover,touchstart,touchend events.